# Deployed WebApi 2 returns old values

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Actually i've updated my WebApi 2 project and deployed the updated version..

The issue is that in one api still return old not updated values..

This is the response of the deployed website

```
[{"TOTPAG":8237.16,"DESCRPAG_PA":"CONTANTI"},{"TOTPAG":63.8,"DESCRPAG_PA":"POS MANUALE"},{"TOTPAG":63.04,"DESCRPAG_PA":"RESI"},{"TOTPAG":12.2,"DESCRPAG_PA":"SATISPAY"},{"TOTPAG":22.0,"DESCRPAG_PA":"TICKET"},{"TOTPAG":12559.82,"DESCRPAG_PA":"VISA+bancom"}]
```

While here is the response of the debug

```
[{"CONT":21229.190000000002,"NONRISC":211.66,"ELET":28922.85,"PAG":[{"TOTPAG":-0.09,"DESCRPAG_PA":"ARROT. L96/17"},{"TOTPAG":1995.88,"DESCRPAG_PA":"cont manuale"},{"TOTPAG":19233.31,"DESCRPAG_PA":"CONTANTI"},{"TOTPAG":149.75,"DESCRPAG_PA":"RESI"},{"TOTPAG":62.0,"DESCRPAG_PA":"TICKET"},{"TOTPAG":28922.85,"DESCRPAG_PA":"VISA+bancom"}]}]
```

Actually the website has been deployed and all files has been updated but it still return the old values that the api responded before the update..

How can i force to update the api response?

Here is how's look's like my controller for the following API

```
<HttpPost()>
<Route("giorno")>
Public Function GetPagamentiGiorno(<FromBody()> ByVal where As ModelConfig.Config)
    Dim re = Request
    Dim headers = re.Headers
    Dim piva As String = ""

    If headers.Contains("authToken") Then
        Dim token As String = headers.GetValues("authToken").First()
        Dim data = TokenManager.Principals(TokenManager.GetPrincipal(token))
        If data Is Nothing Then Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)

        piva = data.piva
    End If

    Dim modelConfig As ModelConfig = New ModelConfig

    Dim pagamenti As Pagamenti = New Pagamenti
    Return Pagamenti.TotalePagamentiGiorno(where.data.inizio, where.data.fine, modelConfig.QueryParametri(where.config, "PA", False), piva)
End Function
```